# Android Here SDK OnPositionChangedListener not called in latest version of SDK

Tags: android, here-api

I've been using HERE Android SDK for some time now.
Today, I updated to the latest version of the SDK(3.2.1) and the OnPositionChangedListener is no longer triggered.

Everything else seems to work( map loading, place search, route calculation, etc).

Any ideas?

Update 03.10.2016:
Just created a fresh project and it still does not work when using PositionManager.( The Map still loads and you can browse it)

The following permissions are set in the Manifest:ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE ).

Below the code in MainActivity.java:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();
 }

private void initialize() {
    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.mapfragment);
    mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(
                OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
            if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                map = mapFragment.getMap();
                map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0),
                        Map.Animation.NONE);
                map.setZoomLevel(
                        (map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                posManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
                posManager.addListener(
                        new WeakReference<PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener>(positionListener));
               boolean startSuccessful = posManager.start(
                        PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK_INDOOR);
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
            }
        }
    });
}
private PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener positionListener
        = new PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPositionUpdated(PositioningManager.LocationMethod locationMethod, GeoPosition geoPosition, boolean b) {
        GeoCoordinate currentCoordinates = geoPosition.getCoordinate();

        map.setCenter(currentCoordinates,
                Map.Animation.NONE);
        map.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionFixChanged(PositioningManager.LocationMethod locationMethod, PositioningManager.LocationStatus locationStatus) {

    }
};
```

Comment: So I tried to get the current position, after Position Manger is started and I get the following result: Lat: -1.7976931348623157E308, Long: -1.7976931348623157E308, Alt: 1.073741824E9. These would seem to be default values for position.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the issue is adding the following in the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

 <!-- HERE Positioning Service definition. -->
    <service
        android:name="com.here.services.internal.LocationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":remote">
    </service>
```

Adding the service above is necessary in order for Positioning to work. It is mentioned only in the new Maps>Here Positioning section of the documentation.

Comment: You will also need to add the BLUTOOTH, BLUETOOH_ADMIN and WAKE_LOCK permissions.

This is a bug which has been reverted, The other way to fix this is to re-register and obtain an updated permission string.

Comment: @DavidLeong Yes, you are correct! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call start method after adding listener.

```
 posManager.addListener(new WeakReference<PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener>(positionListener));
 posManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);
```

Comment: Hi @Akash, as I mentioned in the post the app positioning feature worked before update. Already calling start method.